How to cast to derived class type without dereferencing the base class pointer?
Background
Hello, I am trying to create a way of type checking on casting between derived class types. To do so I want to inform the user when they cast to a type that might cause data loss. Having this functionallity would allow me to dynamically generate data fields that can be written to and read from without really having to know the type. If a cast results in a warning you should change something or the lower level should handle it.
The project
Simplified: What I have is a Base class BaseField and a derived templated class DataField<type>. I have defined a set of casting operators that give me a simple print line to notify the calling of the operator.
class BaseField
{
public:
    operator DataField<int8_t> *()          {std::cout << "Call 1 " << __func__ << std::endl; return nullptr;};
    operator const DataField<int8_t> *()    {std::cout << "Call 2 " << __func__ << std::endl; return nullptr;};
    operator DataField<int8_t> **()         {std::cout << "Call 3 " << __func__ << std::endl; return nullptr;};
    operator int8_t();
}

template <typename T>
class DataField : public BaseField
{
public:
    /**
     * @brief Default constructor
     * 
    **/
    explicit constexpr DataField() = default;

    constexpr auto get() const noexcept -> T;
}

The Test
In another file I have created a std::vector that holds BaseField pointers.
// Create the vector and add 1 item
std::vector<BaseField*> _items;
DataField<int32_t> intItem(10);
_items.push_back(&intItem);
BaseField* item = _items[0];

// Take the Item and cast it into a different derived type
dynamic_cast<DataField<int8_t>*>(item);     // Does not call any of the defined operators
static_cast<DataField<int8_t>*>(item);      // Does not call any of the defined operators
(DataField<int8_t>*)item;                   // Does not call any of the defined operators

(DataField<int8_t>*)&item;                  // Does not call any of the defined operators

static_cast<DataField<int8_t>*>(*item);     // Prints : Call 1 operator DataField<signed char>*
(DataField<int8_t>*)*item;                  // Prints : Call 1 operator DataField<signed char>*


Question
How do I define a user-defined casting operator that works with the first 3 casts? I don't want to always dereference the pointer to cast it to another derived type.

dynamic_cast only works with types that use virtual dispatch.  If you do not have virtual somewhere in the base class then you can't use it to downcast.

Ah yes you are right. The main cast I am interested in is the C style cast > (DataField<int8_t>*)item;  The other ones are there because I got stuck. It does compile :D

"I am trying to create a way of type checking on casting between derived class types" -> just a forewarning: static_cast is iffy, but still works (although it might be an issue when downcasting. C-style casts are even more dangerous as they can fail at runtime. I am not sure how you can prevent those two in order to reduce risks. And another thread on the subject of casting.

When is operator const DataField<int8_t> *() supposed to be used? I can't see it ...

I have to use static_cast or C-style casting sadly enough. My base class can not be templated because I want to store it in a vector and my derived class has a getter method that returns the Templated type. There are no virtual definitions in the base class. Thanks for the references! Always good to get a refresher.

@TedLyngmo It is not in the example, I ran out of things to try out :P

TBH I don't get why can't you just use variant or any. BTW, haven't you just forgotten to forward-declared the derived template? https://godbolt.org/z/sb11hYTWr

@alagner I can't remember but there were some drawbacks with using any or variant, I'll revisit the topic. I am really lost, the code snippet you send works... Same stuff in my full project does not. The forward declaration I have in the file. I guess I have to start breaking down the project to the example and rebuild to see where the issue shows up. Thanks.

@alagner I found the difference between the 2. I use the item from the vector. If you use the vector entry it does not cast anything for some reason. I do not understand why... https://godbolt.org/z/7rEn5d7Wv
On adding the value to the vector I have the instance, afterward, I would need to cast it back into the derived class. That is where I want to detect user error.

Can you state your exact use case, i.e. why do you need this pointer trickery? What you’re doing here most likely causes UB or in a more optimistic case is at least at the edge of it. Why don’t you write sth like a custom wrapper for a pointer?

@alagner I am trying to create a data field that can hold any type but is predefined by a parsed configuration. I want the application to parse a file for me and build a structure out of it using the generic data fields. Each data field will hold a list of other data fields that should be able to be any type again, as well as a sub-structure. It's like a JSON file but then in classes. This would be a way to make that, but any ideas would be welcome :D

I hate to disappoint you, but now it sounds even more like a perfect case for std::any or variant (if limited to a number of types).

Or maybe I'll ask the other way around: why do you insist on using pointers? This should work good enough (probably  could be done better with less exceptions, but this is just for the sake of demonstration).

@alagner You are right! I'll have a look into designing the full structure around any or variants. I was not 100% sure yet if I wanted to commit to C++17, with many embedded frameworks only using C++11, But I guess it is worth it. Thanks for the help and insights!

Conversion operator would be called when you cast the object itself; not the pointer to the object. Consider: struct Data { operator int() { return 42; } }; Data d; static_cast<int>(d); /* calls d.operator int() */ (int)(&d); /* doesn't call operator int() */ In your example, static_cast<DataField<int8_t>*>(*item); would call your operator (note the star in *item)
